# Can I tab inside of align environment?

Tags: math-mode, align

I currently have this ugly equation:

[image]

The green alignment is just like I want it. The Red one is what I would like to get, but I don't know how.

Here is my MWE:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{scrartcl}
\usepackage{amssymb, amsmath} % needed for math
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}   % this is needed for umlauts
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}   % this is needed for umlauts
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}      % this is needed for correct output of umlauts in pdf

\begin{document}
\begin{align}
    f_1(x) &= a \left (x - \frac{b}{3a} \right )^3 + b \left (x-\frac{b}{3a} \right )^2 + c \left (x-\frac{b}{3a} \right ) + d\\
           &= a \left (x^3 - 3 \frac{b}{3a}x^2 + 3 (\frac{b}{3a})^2 x - \frac{b^3}{27a^3} \right )
             +b \left (x^2 - \frac{2b}{3a} x + \frac{b^2}{9a^2} \right )
             +c x - \frac{bc}{3a} + d\\
            &= ax^3 - bx^2 + \frac{b^2}{3a}x - \frac{b^3}{27 a^2}\\
            & \;\;\;\;\;\;+ bx^2 - \frac{2b^2}{3a}x + \frac{b^3}{9a^2}\\
            & \;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\; + c x - \frac{bc}{3a} + d\\
            &= ax^3 + \frac{b^2}{3a}\left (1-2+c \right )x + \frac{b^3}{9a^2} \left (1-\frac{1}{3} \right )- \frac{bc}{3a} + d
\end{align}
\end{document}
```

Comment: if it's not necessary to have every line numbered (the presence of only one equals sign for lines (61-61) hints that one number might do), then a nested `aligned` environment would work.  if all lines need to be numbered, then egreg's answer is the best approach.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just add suitable phantoms:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage{amssymb, amsmath}

\begin{document}
\begin{align}
f_1(x) &= a \left (x - \frac{b}{3a} \right )^3 + b \left (x-\frac{b}{3a} \right )^2
             + c \left (x-\frac{b}{3a} \right ) + d\\
       &= a \left (x^3 - 3 \frac{b}{3a}x^2 + 3 (\frac{b}{3a})^2 x
             - \frac{b^3}{27a^3} \right )
             +b \left (x^2 - \frac{2b}{3a} x + \frac{b^2}{9a^2} \right )
             +c x - \frac{bc}{3a} + d\\
       &= ax^3 - bx^2 + \frac{b^2}{3a}x - \frac{b^3}{27 a^2}\\
       &\hphantom{{}=ax^3}+ bx^2 - \frac{2b^2}{3a}x + \frac{b^3}{9a^2}\\
       &\hphantom{{}=ax^3-bx^2} + c x - \frac{bc}{3a} + d\\
       &= ax^3 + \frac{b^2}{3a} (1-2+c)x + \frac{b^3}{9a^2} \left (1-\frac{1}{3} \right )
             - \frac{bc}{3a} + d
\end{align}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Should equations 3-5 really be three equations?

Comment: This is what the OP seems to want.

Answer (score 4):

In this solution, I used the `tabstackengine` package which is **now available at http://ctan.org/pkg/tabstackengine**.
The package introduces tabbing to the existing features of the `stackengine` package.

So, in this example, I replace the three lines requiring further tabbing with a `\tabbedShortstack`.  I used the default interline gap which is 3pt, but that can be changed with `\setstackgap{S}{length}`.  Also, what showed as three separate equations (3)-(5) in the original should, I think, be only a single equation.

I should also point out that, in `tabstackengine`, the default tabbing character is `&` and the default end-of-line character is `\\`, but that I had to reset those as to not conflict within the `align` environment.

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{scrartcl}
\usepackage{amssymb, amsmath} % needed for math
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}   % this is needed for umlauts
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}   % this is needed for umlauts
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}      % this is needed for correct output of umlauts in pdf
\usepackage{tabstackengine}
\setstackEOL{@}
\setstackTAB{*}
\stackMath
\begin{document}
\begin{align}
    f_1(x) &= a \left (x - \frac{b}{3a} \right )^3 + b \left (x-\frac{b}{3a} \right )^2 + c \left (x-\frac{b}{3a} \right ) + d\\
           &= a \left (x^3 - 3 \frac{b}{3a}x^2 + 3 (\frac{b}{3a})^2 x - \frac{b^3}{27a^3} \right )
             +b \left (x^2 - \frac{2b}{3a} x + \frac{b^2}{9a^2} \right )
             +c x - \frac{bc}{3a} + d\\
&\tabbedShortstack{%
            = ax^3 *- bx^2 *+ \dfrac{b^2}{3a}x - \dfrac{b^3}{27 a^2}@
            * + bx^2 *- \dfrac{2b^2}{3a}x + \dfrac{b^3}{9a^2}@
            **+ c x - \dfrac{bc}{3a} + d%
}\\
            &= ax^3 + \frac{b^2}{3a}\left (1-2+c \right )x + \frac{b^3}{9a^2} \left (1-\frac{1}{3} \right )- \frac{bc}{3a} + d
\end{align}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Just for edification regarding the `tabstackengine` package, some of its commands include

[image]