# replacing eqnarray when several alignment tabs are present

Tags: math-mode, align, obsolete

I have three mathematical equations which I would like to have typeset in one block such that they are aligned at the equality sign `=` and the following comment.
Up until now, I've been using `eqnarray`

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}
\begin{eqnarray}
  \begin{aligned}
    aaa & = b   &\text{ in } Q\\
    c   & = d   &\text{ in } \Sigma\\
    e   & = fff &\text{ in } \Omega
  \end{aligned}
\end{eqnarray}
\end{document}
```

but I understand that this environment is obsolete (as per [l2tabu](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/l2tabu)).

What would be a better alternative?

Comment: A more complete (local) reference is: [`eqnarray` vs `align`](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/196/5764)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think the following is what you are looking for:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\begin{gather}
\begin{aligned}
  aaa &= b   &&\text{in $Q$}\\
  c   &= d   &&\text{in $\Sigma$}\\
  e   &= fff &&\text{in $\Omega$}
\end{aligned}
\end{gather}

\end{document}
```

[image: output]

Note the two consecutive ampersands (`&&`); this left-align the three "in .." blocks instead of align them to the right of the symbols.

P.S. [Don't use `eqnarray`](http://www.tug.org/TUGboat/tb33-1/tb103madsen.pdf) at all.

Answer (score 2):

The not yet released `tabstackengine` package can do this.  It was introduced at [Writing a table with equally spaced columns, based on the widest column](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/139771/writing-a-table-with-equally-spaced-columns-based-on-the-widest-column/139946#139946) and the sty file can be found at [Measuring align](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/142406/measuring-align/142608#142608).

The package extends the macros of the `stackengine` package by adding tabbing commands.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{tabstackengine}
\stackMath
\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
  \alignCenterstack{
    aaa & = b   &\text{ in } Q\\
    c   & = d   &\text{ in } \Sigma\\
    e   & = fff &\text{ in } \Omega
  }
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: This is nice but not very useful before your package is released. `:(`

Comment: @SvendTveskæg Yes I must redouble my efforts to finish up the project.

Comment: @SvendTveskæg  You can see http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/148669/can-i-tab-inside-of-align-environment/148684#148684 for a list of some of the commands available to the package.