# Side to side sum+product of matrices

Tags: matrices

I have been trying to write these matrices which are the results of a cointegration problem. However, I'm struggling to write down the second member of my matrices. As you can this is my code:

```
\begin{pmatrix}
\Delta A \\ \Delta BC \\ \Delta NB \\  \Delta NS \\  \Delta ON \\ \Delta Q  \\
\end{pmatrix}
\]
=
\[
\begin{pmatrix}
0.36 & 0.09 & 0.04 & -0.40 & 0.26 & -0.36\\ 
0.28 & -0.08& 0.04& -0.14& 0.28& -0.13\\
0.16 & -0.01 & -0.08 & -0.009 & 0.57 & -0.64\\
0.36 &  0.19 &  -0.34 & -0.20 &  0.35 &  0.03\\
0.18 &   0.15 & 0.08 &  -0.07 & -0.03 & -0.32\\
0.08 & 0.41 & -0.10 & -0.20 & 0.34 & -0.48\\
\end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix}
\Delta A(-1) \\ \Delta BC(-1) \\ \Delta NB(-1) \\  \Delta NS(-1) \\  \Delta ON(-1) \\  \Delta Q(-1) \\
\end{pmatrix}

+

\begin{pmatrix}

-0.84 & 0.21 & -0.11 & 0.110 & 0.13 & 0.34\\ 
0.21 & -0.43 & 0.14 & 0.06 & 0.30 & -0.22\\
0.27 & 0.13 & -0.54 & 0.25 & -0.27 & 0.16\\
-0.27 &  -0.23 &  0.43 & -0.46 &  0.53 & -0.05\\
0.05 &   0.13 & -0.02 &  -0.10 & -0.03 & -0.02\\
0.23 & -0.32 & 0.21 & -0.11 & 0.41 & -0.34\\

\end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix}
 A(-1) \\ BC(-1) \\ \ NB(-1) \\  \ NS(-1) \\  \ON(-1) \\  \Q(-1) \\
\end{pmatrix}

+
\begin{pmatrix}
 12.10 \\ -4.97 \\ -1.12 \\  4.56 \\  0.10 \\  -5.85 \\
\end{pmatrix}
```

Can someone tells me how i improves my codes in order to get the results on the picture?

[image]

Comment: is this a discrete time state space representation of a nonlinear system ?

Comment: @percusse, Nope. It is the representation of the Vector of error correction model. I derived this from the cointegration approach.

Comment: Well in some coordinate transformation it's the same thing. You are updating recursively I think so better keep the matrices away from the *equations of motion* to emphasize the mechanism.

Answer (score 7):

The `multline*` environment can help you here. It is a multiline math environment from `amsmath` that left aligns the first line, right aligns the last, and center aligns the rest. Add a linebreak with `\\`, and replace `pmatrix` with `bmatrix`to get braces rather than parentheses as matrix delimiters.

Also note that empty lines are normally not allowed in display math environments.

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\begin{multline*}
\begin{bmatrix}
\Delta A \\ \Delta BC \\ \Delta NB \\  \Delta NS \\  \Delta ON \\ \Delta Q  \\
\end{bmatrix}
=
\begin{bmatrix}
0.36 & 0.09 & 0.04 & -0.40 & 0.26 & -0.36\\ 
0.28 & -0.08& 0.04& -0.14& 0.28& -0.13\\
0.16 & -0.01 & -0.08 & -0.009 & 0.57 & -0.64\\
0.36 &  0.19 &  -0.34 & -0.20 &  0.35 &  0.03\\
0.18 &   0.15 & 0.08 &  -0.07 & -0.03 & -0.32\\
0.08 & 0.41 & -0.10 & -0.20 & 0.34 & -0.48\\
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
\Delta A(-1) \\ \Delta BC(-1) \\ \Delta NB(-1) \\  \Delta NS(-1) \\  \Delta ON(-1) \\  \Delta Q(-1) \\
\end{bmatrix}
+ \\
\begin{bmatrix}
-0.84 & 0.21 & -0.11 & 0.110 & 0.13 & 0.34\\ 
0.21 & -0.43 & 0.14 & 0.06 & 0.30 & -0.22\\
0.27 & 0.13 & -0.54 & 0.25 & -0.27 & 0.16\\
-0.27 &  -0.23 &  0.43 & -0.46 &  0.53 & -0.05\\
0.05 &   0.13 & -0.02 &  -0.10 & -0.03 & -0.02\\
0.23 & -0.32 & 0.21 & -0.11 & 0.41 & -0.34\\
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
 A(-1) \\ BC(-1) \\ \ NB(-1) \\  \ NS(-1) \\  ON(-1) \\  Q(-1) \\
\end{bmatrix}
+
\begin{bmatrix}
 12.10 \\ -4.97 \\ -1.12 \\  4.56 \\  0.10 \\  -5.85 \\
\end{bmatrix}
\end{multline*}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

I would use `align*` to do this since you have two lines.

```
\begin{align*}
\begin{bmatrix} \Delta A \\ \Delta BC \\ \Delta NB \\ \Delta NS \\ \Delta ON \\ \Delta Q  \end{bmatrix} &=
 \begin{bmatrix} 0.36 & 0.09 & 0.04 & -0.40 & 0.26 & -0.36\\ 0.28 & -0.08& 0.04& -0.14& 0.28& -0.13\\ 0.16 & -0.01 & -0.08 & -0.009 & 0.57 & -0.64\\ 0.36 & 0.19 & -0.34 & -0.20 & 0.35 & 0.03\\ 0.18 & 0.15 & 0.08 & -0.07 & -0.03 & -0.32\\ 0.08 & 0.41 & -0.10 & -0.20 & 0.34 & -0.48 \end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix} \Delta A(-1) \\ \Delta BC(-1) \\ \Delta NB(-1) \\ \Delta NS(-1) \\ \Delta ON(-1) \\ \Delta Q(-1)  \end{bmatrix} \\
&{\quad{}} + 
\begin{bmatrix}
-0.84 & 0.21 & -0.11 & 0.110 & 0.13 & 0.34\\ 0.21 & -0.43 & 0.14 & 0.06 & 0.30 & -0.22\\ 0.27 & 0.13 & -0.54 & 0.25 & -0.27 & 0.16\\ -0.27 & -0.23 & 0.43 & -0.46 & 0.53 & -0.05\\ 0.05 & 0.13 & -0.02 & -0.10 & -0.03 & -0.02\\ 0.23 & -0.32 & 0.21 & -0.11 & 0.41 & -0.34
\end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix} A(-1) \\ BC(-1) \\ NB(-1) \\ NS(-1) \\ ON(-1) \\ Q(-1)  \end{bmatrix}
+ \begin{bmatrix} 12.10 \\ -4.97 \\ -1.12 \\ 4.56 \\ 0.10 \\ -5.85 \ \end{bmatrix}
\end{align*}
```

[image]

Comment: Yeah it is working now with your code. Thanks

Answer (score 4):

As I just noted on another answer...

---

This is using the under-development `tabstackengine` package, first introduced here at [Writing a table with equally spaced columns, based on the widest column](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/139771/writing-a-table-with-equally-spaced-columns-based-on-the-widest-column/139946#139946) (source code available at [Measuring align](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/142406/measuring-align/142608#142608)).

The package extends the `stackengine` package by adding tabbing capability.  This answer, [Can I tab inside of align environment?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/148669/can-i-tab-inside-of-align-environment/148684#148684), gives some of the syntax of the package.  I apologize that I have been lax in completing the package and getting it out the door, so the only way to see it in action is by searching this site for `tabstackengine`.

---

But I noticed on this question that all answers have center alignment on the matrices which looks unappealing to me, so I thought I would provide an alternative.  By using stacks to compose the individual vectors and matrices, the alignment may be individually specified for each one.  Thus, I retained center alignment on the terms involving symbolic variables and right alignment for matrices involving real numbers.  The space between the two matrix rows is controlled by the `[10pt]` optional argument to `\stackunder`.  To get the minus signs to be unary, I needed to enclose them in braces.  That would appear to be a deficiency of the package that I have not yet resolved, but the workaround is the braces.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fixltx2e}
\usepackage{tabstackengine}
\stackMath
\setstacktabbedgap{1ex}
\begin{document}
\[
\renewcommand\stackalignment{l}
\stackunder[10pt]{%
\renewcommand\stackalignment{c}
\bracketVectorstack{
\Delta A \\ \Delta BC \\ \Delta NB \\  \Delta NS \\  \Delta ON \\ \Delta Q
}
=
\renewcommand\stackalignment{r}
\bracketMatrixstack{
0.36 & 0.09 & 0.04 & {-}0.40 & 0.26 & {-}0.36\\ 
0.28 & {-}0.08& 0.04& {-}0.14& 0.28& {-}0.13\\
0.16 & {-}0.01 & {-}0.08 & {-}0.009 & 0.57 & {-}0.64\\
0.36 &  0.19 &  {-}0.34 & {-}0.20 &  0.35 &  0.03\\
0.18 &   0.15 & 0.08 &  {-}0.07 & {-}0.03 & {-}0.32\\
0.08 & 0.41 & {-}0.10 & {-}0.20 & 0.34 & {-}0.48
}
\renewcommand\stackalignment{c}
\bracketVectorstack{
\Delta A({-}1) \\ \Delta BC({-}1) \\ \Delta NB({-}1) \\  \Delta NS({-}1) \\  \Delta ON({-}1) \\  \Delta Q({-}1)
}
+%
}{%
\hspace{12ex}%
\renewcommand\stackalignment{r}
\bracketMatrixstack{
{-}0.84 & 0.21 & {-}0.11 & 0.110 & 0.13 & 0.34\\ 
0.21 & {-}0.43 & 0.14 & 0.06 & 0.30 & {-}0.22\\
0.27 & 0.13 & {-}0.54 & 0.25 & {-}0.27 & 0.16\\
{-}0.27 &  {-}0.23 &  0.43 & {-}0.46 &  0.53 & {-}0.05\\
0.05 &   0.13 & {-}0.02 &  {-}0.10 & {-}0.03 & {-}0.02\\
0.23 & {-}0.32 & 0.21 & {-}0.11 & 0.41 & {-}0.34
}
\renewcommand\stackalignment{c}
\bracketVectorstack{
 A({-}1) \\ BC({-}1) \\ NB({-}1) \\  NS({-}1) \\  ON({-}1) \\  Q({-}1)
}
+
\renewcommand\stackalignment{r}
\bracketVectorstack{
 12.10 \\ {-}4.97 \\ {-}1.12 \\  4.56 \\  0.10 \\  {-}5.85
}%
}
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Similar in spirit to the answer by @StevenBSegletes (and borrowing some code from the answer by Torbjørn T.), but using the `dcolumn` package and the basic `array` environment to align the columns of numbers on their decimal markers:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,dcolumn}
\newcolumntype{d}{D..{2.2}} % for decimal-aligned numbers
\begin{document}
\begin{multline*}
\begin{bmatrix}
\Delta A \\ \Delta BC \\ \Delta NB \\  \Delta NS \\  \Delta ON \\ \Delta Q  \\
\end{bmatrix}
=
\left[\begin{array}{@{} *{6}{d}}
0.36 & 0.09 & 0.04 & -0.40 & 0.26 & -0.36\\ 
0.28 & -0.08& 0.04& -0.14& 0.28& -0.13\\
0.16 & -0.01 & -0.08 & -0.009 & 0.57 & -0.64\\
0.36 &  0.19 &  -0.34 & -0.20 &  0.35 &  0.03\\
0.18 &   0.15 & 0.08 &  -0.07 & -0.03 & -0.32\\
0.08 & 0.41 & -0.10 & -0.20 & 0.34 & -0.48\\
\end{array}\right]
\begin{bmatrix}
\Delta A(-1) \\ \Delta BC(-1) \\ \Delta NB(-1) \\  \Delta NS(-1) \\  \Delta ON(-1) \\  \Delta Q(-1) \\
\end{bmatrix}
+ \\
\left[\begin{array}{*{6}{d}}
-0.84 & 0.21 & -0.11 & 0.110 & 0.13 & 0.34\\ 
0.21 & -0.43 & 0.14 & 0.06 & 0.30 & -0.22\\
0.27 & 0.13 & -0.54 & 0.25 & -0.27 & 0.16\\
-0.27 &  -0.23 &  0.43 & -0.46 &  0.53 & -0.05\\
0.05 &   0.13 & -0.02 &  -0.10 & -0.03 & -0.02\\
0.23 & -0.32 & 0.21 & -0.11 & 0.41 & -0.34\\
\end{array}\right]
\begin{bmatrix}
 A(-1) \\ BC(-1) \\ \ NB(-1) \\  \ NS(-1) \\  ON(-1) \\  Q(-1) \\
\end{bmatrix}
+
\left[\begin{array}{d}
 12.10 \\ -4.97 \\ -1.12 \\  4.56 \\  0.10 \\  -5.85 \\
\end{array}\right]
\end{multline*}
\end{document}
```