# How to stretch horizontal length

Tags: spacing

In this [paper](http://cr.yp.to/snuffle/spec.pdf), Daniel J. Bernstein used horizontally stretched lines [image: see this] (page 7). I was trying to do the same. I saw [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/50508/fully-stretch-text-horizontally-on-page) question, but none of the answers could produce the desired result. Can anybody help?

Comment: Do you want it stretched to a fixed width, say `\textwidth`, or do you just want the ability to add arbitrary space between the column elements?

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes Arbitrary spacing between column elements may not look fancy (I am dealing with probability values- up to 4 places of decimal). I think the style used here is add space to the elements to make the number of digits equal to 3.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's an implementation using LaTeX3 functions. I added also the simpler case of hexadecimal input.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,xparse}
\newcommand\op[1]{\operatorname{#1}}
\newcommand\he[1]{\mathtt{0x#1}}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand{\fl}{m}
 {
  \pushpen_fl:n { #1 }
 }

\dim_new:N \l_pushpen_digit_dim
\seq_new:N \l_pushpen_input_seq
\seq_new:N \l_pushpen_output_seq

\cs_new_protected:Npn \pushpen_fl:n #1
 {
  \hbox_set:Nn \l_tmpa_box { 0 }
  \dim_set:Nn \l_pushpen_digit_dim { 3\box_wd:N \l_tmpa_box }
  \seq_set_split:Nnn \l_pushpen_input_seq { , } { #1 }
  \seq_clear:N \l_pushpen_output_seq
  \seq_map_inline:Nn \l_pushpen_input_seq
   {
    \seq_put_right:Nn \l_pushpen_output_seq { \makebox[\l_pushpen_digit_dim][r]{##1} }
   }
  \seq_use:Nn \l_pushpen_output_seq { , }
 }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}
\begin{align*}
\op{doubleround}(
&\he{00000001}, \he{00000000}, \he{00000000}, \he{00000000},\\
&\he{00000000}, \he{00000000}, \he{00000000}, \he{00000000},\\
&\he{00000000}, \he{00000000}, \he{00000000}, \he{00000000},\\
&\he{00000000}, \he{00000000}, \he{00000000}, \he{00000000})\\
=(
&\he{8186a22d}, \he{0040a284}, \he{82479210}, \he{06929051},\\
&\he{08000090}, \he{02402200}, \he{00004000}, \he{00800000},\\
&\he{00010200}, \he{20400000}, \he{08008104}, \he{00000000},\\
&\he{20500000}, \he{a0000040}, \he{0008180a}, \he{612a8020}).\\
\op{doubleround}(
&\he{de501066}, \he{6f9eb8f7}, \he{e4fbbd9b}, \he{454e3f57},\\
&\he{b75540d3}, \he{43e93a4c}, \he{3a6f2aa0}, \he{726d6b36},\\
&\he{9243f484}, \he{9145d1e8}, \he{4fa9d247}, \he{dc8dee11},\\
&\he{054bf545}, \he{254dd653}, \he{d9421b6d}, \he{67b276c1})\\
=(
&\he{ccaaf672}, \he{23d960f7}, \he{9153e63a}, \he{cd9a60d0},\\
&\he{50440492}, \he{f07cad19}, \he{ae344aa0}, \he{df4cfdfc},\\
&\he{ca531c29}, \he{8e7943db}, \he{ac1680cd}, \he{d503ca00},\\
&\he{a74b2ad6}, \he{bc331c5c}, \he{1dda24c7}, \he{ee928277}).
\end{align*}
Another example with decimal digits:
\begin{align*}
\op{Salsa20}(
&\fl{0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0},\\
&\fl{0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0},\\
&\fl{0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0},\\
&\fl{0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0})\\
=(
&\fl{0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0},\\
&\fl{0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0},\\
&\fl{0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0},\\
&\fl{0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}).\\
\op{Salsa20}(
&\fl{211,159, 13,115, 76, 55, 82,183,  3,117,222, 37,191,187,234,136},\\
&\fl{ 49,237,179, 48,  1,106,178,219,175,199,166, 48, 86, 16,179,207},\\
&\fl{ 31,240, 32, 63, 15, 83, 93,161,116,147, 48,113,238, 55,204, 36},\\
&\fl{ 79,201,235, 79,  3, 81,156, 47,203, 26,244,243, 88,118,104, 54})\\
=(
&\fl{109, 42,178,168,156,240,248,238,168,196,190,203, 26,110,170,154},\\
&\fl{ 29, 29,150, 26,150, 30,235,249,190,163,251, 48, 69,144, 51, 57},\\
&\fl{118, 40,152,157,180, 57, 27, 94,107, 42,236, 35, 27,111,114,114},\\
&\fl{219,236,232,135,111,155,110, 18, 24,232, 95,158,179, 19, 48,202}).
\end{align*}

\end{document}
```

[image]

A version with simplified syntax for inputting the values; similar ideas could be used for the hexadecimal output.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,xparse}
\newcommand\op[1]{\operatorname{#1}}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand{\fl}{m}
 {
  \pushpen_fl:n { #1 }
 }

\dim_new:N \g_pushpen_digit_dim
\seq_new:N \l_pushpen_input_seq
\seq_new:N \l_pushpen_output_seq
\int_new:N \l_pushpen_step_int

\cs_new_protected:Npn \pushpen_fl:n #1
 {
  \hbox_set:Nn \l_tmpa_box { 0 }
  \dim_gset:Nn \g_pushpen_digit_dim { 3\box_wd:N \l_tmpa_box }
  \int_zero:N \l_pushpen_step_int
  \seq_set_split:Nnn \l_pushpen_input_seq { , } { #1 }
  \seq_clear:N \l_pushpen_output_seq
  \seq_put_right:Nn \l_pushpen_output_seq { ( & } % initialize
  \seq_map_inline:Nn \l_pushpen_input_seq
   {
    \int_incr:N \l_pushpen_step_int
    \seq_put_right:Nn \l_pushpen_output_seq { \makebox[\g_pushpen_digit_dim][r]{##1} }
    \int_compare:nTF { \l_pushpen_step_int == 64 } % we're doing the last item
     {
      \seq_put_right:Nn \l_pushpen_output_seq { ) }
     }
     {
      \int_compare:nTF { \int_mod:nn { \l_pushpen_step_int } { 16 } == 0 } % end of row
       {
        \seq_put_right:Nn \l_pushpen_output_seq { , \\ & }
       }
       {
        \seq_put_right:Nn \l_pushpen_output_seq { , }
       }
     }
   }
  \seq_use:Nn \l_pushpen_output_seq { }
 }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}
\begin{align*}
\op{Salsa20}
\fl{
  0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
  0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
  0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
  0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0
}\\
=
\fl{
  0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
  0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
  0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
  0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0
}.\\
\op{Salsa20}
\fl{
  211,159, 13,115, 76, 55, 82,183,  3,117,222, 37,191,187,234,136,
   49,237,179, 48,  1,106,178,219,175,199,166, 48, 86, 16,179,207,
   31,240, 32, 63, 15, 83, 93,161,116,147, 48,113,238, 55,204, 36,
   79,201,235, 79,  3, 81,156, 47,203, 26,244,243, 88,118,104, 54
}\\
=
\fl{
  109, 42,178,168,156,240,248,238,168,196,190,203, 26,110,170,154,
   29, 29,150, 26,150, 30,235,249,190,163,251, 48, 69,144, 51, 57,
  118, 40,152,157,180, 57, 27, 94,107, 42,236, 35, 27,111,114,114,
  219,236,232,135,111,155,110, 18, 24,232, 95,158,179, 19, 48,202
}.
\end{align*}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: carefully compare the space around the commas between "triplets" in this last example with the corresponding commas as shown in the original questions.  in the original, there is no "extra" space following a comma between adjacent full triplets.  this effect can be obtained by entering the commas as `{,}`; see the *texbook*, p.134.

Comment: @barbarabeeton I believe that not leaving a space is wrong.

Answer (score 4):

For the `array`-inclined, here's a regular implementation:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,array}% http://ctan.org/pkg/{amsmath,array}
\begin{document}
\[
  \settowidth{\dimen0}{$000$}% Capture widest element
  \begin{array}{r@{}*{15}{>{\raggedleft}p{\dimen0}@{,{} }}>{\raggedleft\arraybackslash}p{\dimen0}@{}l}
    \text{Salsa20}(&   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 & , \\
                   &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 & , \\
                   &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 & , \\
                   &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 & ) \\
               {}=(&   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 & , \\
                   &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 & , \\
                   &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 & , \\
                   &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 & ). \\
    \text{Salsa20}(& 211 & 159 &  13 & 115 &  76 &  55 &  82 & 183 &   3 & 117 & 222 &  37 & 191 & 187 & 234 & 136 & , \\
                   &  49 & 237 & 179 &  48 &   1 & 106 & 178 & 219 & 175 & 199 & 166 &  48 &  86 &  16 & 179 & 207 & , \\
                   &  31 & 240 &  32 &  63 &  15 &  83 &  93 & 161 & 116 & 147 &  48 & 113 & 238 &  55 & 204 &  36 & , \\
                   &  79 & 201 & 235 &  79 &   3 &  81 & 156 &  47 & 203 &  26 & 244 & 243 &  88 & 118 & 104 &  54 & ) \\
               {}=(& 109 &  42 & 178 & 168 & 156 & 240 & 248 & 238 & 168 & 196 & 190 & 203 &  26 & 110 & 170 & 154 & , \\
                   &  29 &  29 & 150 &  26 & 150 &  30 & 235 & 249 & 190 & 163 & 251 &  48 &  69 & 144 &  51 &  57 & , \\
                   & 118 &  40 & 152 & 157 & 180 &  57 &  27 &  94 & 107 &  42 & 236 &  35 &  27 & 111 & 114 & 114 & , \\
                   & 219 & 236 & 232 & 135 & 111 & 155 & 110 &  18 &  24 & 232 &  95 & 158 & 179 &  19 &  48 & 202 & ).
  \end{array}
\]
\end{document}
```

[`array`](http://ctan.org/pkg/array) is used for right-alignment within the cells, while [`amsmath`](http://ctan.org/pkg/amsmath) provides `\text`.

Comment: It should be `\sbox{0}{$000$}` and `\wd0` (odd numbered scratch registers should be used globally). Why not simply `\settowidth{\dimen0}{$000$}`?

Comment: @egreg: Grazie!

Answer (score 3):

This is using the under-development `tabstackengine` package, first introduced here at [Writing a table with equally spaced columns, based on the widest column](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/139771/writing-a-table-with-equally-spaced-columns-based-on-the-widest-column/139946#139946) (source code available at [Measuring align](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/142406/measuring-align/142608#142608)).

The package extends the `stackengine` package by adding tabbing capability.  This answer, [Can I tab inside of align environment?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/148669/can-i-tab-inside-of-align-environment/148684#148684), gives some of the syntax of the package.  I apologize that I have been lax in completing the package and getting it out the door, so the only way to see it in action is by searching this site for `tabstackengine`.

---

In this case, a tabbed long-understack allows a uniform gap between each column to be set, in this case, I set the tab to .5ex (the "long" means each row is of uniform baseline-to-baseline spacing, and the "under" means that the overall baseline is set at the top row of the stack).  I did require several `\rlap`s/`\phantom`s as corrections for the closing parenthesis, and a `\phantom` to widen a column with only 2 digits of data.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabstackengine}
\textwidth 6.5in
\begin{document}
\setstacktabbedgap{.5ex}
\noindent Salsa20
\tabbedLongunderstack[r]{
(211;&159;& 13;&115;& \protect\phantom{1}76;& 55;& 82;&183;& 3;&117;&222;& 37;&191;&187;&234;&136;\\
49;&237;&179;& 48;& 1;&106;&178;&219;&175;&199;&166;& 48;& 86;& 16;&179;&207;\\
31;&240;& 32;& 63;& 15;& 83;& 93;&161;&116;&147;& 48;&113;&238;& 55;&204;& 36;\\
79;&201;&235;& 79;& 3;& 81;&156;& 47;&203;& 26;&244;&243;& 88;&118;&104;& 54\rlap{):}\protect\phantom{;}
}\\
\makebox[\widthof{Salsa20}][r]{=}
\tabbedLongunderstack[r]{
(109;& 42;&178;&168;&156;&240;&248;&238;&168;&196;&190;&203;& 26;&110;&170;&154;\\
29;& 29;&150;& 26;&150;& 30;&235;&249;&190;&163;&251;& 48;& 69;&144;& 51;& 57;\\
118;& 40;&152;&157;&180;& 57;& 27;& 94;&107;& 42;&236;& 35;& 27;&111;&114;&114;\\
219;&236;&232;&135;&111;&155;&110;& 18;& 24;&232;& 95;&158;&179;& 19;& 48;&202\rlap{):}\protect\phantom{;}
}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I think the use of `\kern1.1ex` in column 5 should be replaced with `\phantom{1}`. Also, why the final `\kern`s?

Comment: @Werner The final kern before the `&` makes sure the last number aligns with the last number in the row above, rather than with the semicolon.  The final kern following the `&` moves the paren to the left, so that there is no gap between the final number and the right paren.  In column 5, I used a kern because it needed to be protected and `\protect\phantom{1}` took more typing than a kern, but you are correct it should be that.  I'll revise and correct the missing links, too.

Comment: For the final `\kern`s, you could also use `\rlap{):}\phantom{;}` (with some protection, perhaps). I think it's always good to use `\phantom`s to have proper alignment, rather than using font-specific widths.