# How to align the middle of some words

Tags: align

I want to align the middle of a "word" with something else. Let me explain. The following is what I have.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\begin{align*}
a&:=b\\
c&=d
\end{align*}
\end{document}
```

This looks okay, but I really want the two equal signs to be what we are aligning. So the obvious thing to do is to more the `&` to the other side of the `:`, as follows.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\begin{align*}
a:&=b\\
c&=d
\end{align*}
\end{document}
```

But, of course, this was never going to work! You end up with a space between the colon and the equals sign, `: =` as opposed to `:=`. So you see my problem...

Comment: Thanks for accepting my answer.  You should know that I just uploaded the `tabstackengine` package to CTAN within the last hour, and so it should be available for download (including documentation) in the coming days.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is using the under-development `tabstackengine` package, first introduced here at [Writing a table with equally spaced columns, based on the widest column](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/139771/writing-a-table-with-equally-spaced-columns-based-on-the-widest-column/139946#139946) (source code available at [Measuring align](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/142406/measuring-align/142608#142608)).

The package extends the `stackengine` package by adding tabbing capability.  This answer, [Can I tab inside of align environment?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/148669/can-i-tab-inside-of-align-environment/148684#148684), gives some of the syntax of the package.  I apologize that I have been lax in completing the package and getting it out the door, so the only way to see it in action is by searching this site for `tabstackengine`.

---

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabstackengine}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\stackMath
\begin{document}
\begin{equation*}
\setstacktabulargap{0pt}
\tabularCenterstack{lrl}{%
a&:=&b\\
c&=&d
}
\end{equation*}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Is the following what you are looking for?

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{mathtools}

\begin{document}

\begin{align*}
  a \coloneqq{} &b\\
  c ={}         &d
\end{align*}

\end{document}
```

[image: output1]

Maybe

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{mathtools}

\begin{document}

\begin{alignat*}{2}
  &a &{}\coloneqq{} &b\\
  &c &{}={}         &d
\end{alignat*}

\end{document}
```

[image: output2]

is (more) useful?

Note: `\coloneqq` from [`mathtools`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/mathtools) gives the correct symbol for dynamic definition (or whatever it is).

Comment: What are the curly brackets doing here?

Comment: @user1729 They give the correct horizontal spacing. Try my examples; remove them and see what happens. `:)`

Comment: I figured that that was approximately what they did, but I do not understand what you mean by "correct". Do they put a single space between the end of one row and the beginning of next?

Comment: @user1729 As I say, try it. `:)` You'll learn much more by seeing it fo yourself.

Comment: A mathematical relation at the beginning or end of a math environment is not treated as a relation (is not surrounded by "relation space"). The braces supply something on the other side so it is treated as a relation and so surrounded by space. The AMS alignment environments supply their own `{}` after the `&` so they are not needed for things like `&=`, although they would not do any harm.

Answer (score 3):

If a bigger space in the second equation is acceptable, the following is working quite easy. In this very case, the right side aligning of the left terms actually looks quite nice.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\begin{align*}
a&:=b\\
c&\phantom{:}=d
\end{align*}
\end{document}
```

[image]

For the use of the better looking `\coloneqq` of the package `mathtools`, just align on the right side of the equations: `={}&`

Comment: This is the perfect fix for my own situation. Thanks! Although I feel that one of the other answers will be of more help to others so I hope you are not offended when I don't accept yours...

Comment: hehe, accept what ever you want. That was not such a great effort...

Comment: I disagree - this is a wonderful effort! Obvious and elegant is much better than complicated...