# Issue with \\ in custom command

Tags: macros, matrices

So I'm trying to make my own command to make matrices less painful

My current command is:

```
\newcommand{\mat}[2]{
\left(\begin{array}{#1}{#2}\end{array}\right)}
```

with the intention to use it as:

```
\mat{cc}{1&0\\0&1}
```

producing the same thing as

```
\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
1 & 0 \\
0 & 1
\end{array}\right)
```

But I keep getting the message "Missing } inserted." I think it doesn't like the \\ in the command argument.

Any suggestions?

Edit: Fixed it. Removed the brace group from the macro

Comment: See the `tabstackengine` package.  It does this already.  Either `\tabularCenterstack` or `\parenMatrixstack` should do the trick.  See http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/139771/writing-a-table-with-equally-spaced-columns-based-on-the-widest-column/139946#139946, and http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/148669/can-i-tab-inside-of-align-environment/148684#148684

Comment: Thanks, but I'm also just curious as to why this isn't working

Comment: This may very well not be the problem, but I *really* don't think you should wrap `#2` in a brace group.  (And welcome to TeX.SX!) I don't think ``\\`` likes being in a brace group.

Comment: thank you. Getting rid of the brace group fixed the problem!

Comment: Glad to help—don't forget you can accept the answer soon :) That's the way we publicly say 'thank you' on the SE network, and it's a good way of telling everyone that your issue is resolved.

Comment: A general view of matrix construction is available in [Where is the `\matrix` command?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/26434/5764)

Answer (score 8):

Remove the spurious braces in your definition:

```
\documentclass{article}
\newcommand{\mat}[2]{
  \left(
  \begin{array}{#1}
    #2
  \end{array}
  \right)
}
\begin{document}
\[ \mat{c}{2\\3} \]
\end{document}
```

#### Why is this necessary?

Brace groups are kind of a special thing in TeX
  (take a look at TeX by Topic for detailed information; run `texdoc texbytopic` in your terminal).
When you put something in a brace group,
  you are asking TeX to process it as a unit.
The problem is, with `array` there are many things that need to be dealt with as individual units inside, such as rows.
(The *real* reason actually has to do with things like 'vertical mode' and 'horizontal mode', but the above explanation will hold for many other things.)

Comment: But this approach still will not work with alignment tabs (&) though, or am I missing something?

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes it does work.

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes The real problem is that TeX is switching from horizontal mode into vertical mode when it encounters the break—this can't really be done in a brace group to the best of my understanding.  The alignment character doesn't switch modes, so it's alright.

Answer (score 1):

The `tabstackengine` package does this already, as I mentioned in my comment.  The first form gives the parens with the stack, but all columns must be of the same alignment.  The second form needs the parens added separately, but allows each column to have its own alignment.

The examples below are not pretty, but are merely meant to demonstrate these alignment variations.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabstackengine}
\parskip 1ex
\begin{document}
\setstacktabbedgap{1ex}
$\parenMatrixstack[r]{1 & 23 \\34 & 1}$\par
\setstacktabulargap{1ex}
$\left(\tabularCenterstack{lc}{1 & 23 \\34 & 1} \right)$
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: If possible though, I'd like to be able to do it using vanilla latex. Making my own macros is about getting better at latex as much as it is about anything else

Comment: @sicklybeans Understood.  Best wishes.  Welcome to the site.